# Unable to use img with background-image: url()

Tags: html, css, sass

I am having trouble to display my image in background of my html.

```
 <div class="item active" style="background-image:URL("/img/abc-1.jpg");"></div>
```

Why the url cant display my img instead, in the inspection I have done in google chrome, it shows out:

```
<div class="item active" style="background-image:URL(img abc-1.jpg);"></div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you made a mistakes.
I think you are referring to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp).

The correct way to do it is:
`<div class="item active" style="background-image:URL('/img/abc-1.jpg');"></div>`

without the double quotation mark

Answer (score 0):

Change the double quotes to single quotes:

```
<div class="item active" style="background-image:URL('/img/abc-1.jpg');"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Need to use single quotes '' like this: `style="background-image:url('/img/abc-1.jpg')`

This way you escape the "" double quotes used on the style property.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the double quotes, use escape sequence. This won't close the style attribute.

```
<div class="item active" style="background-image:URL(\"img abc-1.jpg\");"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Background Url should be written within single Quotes, you have used double quotes because of which style tag technically closes at **`style="background-image:URL("`**

Try using single quotes **`style="background-image:URL('/img/abc-1.jpg');"`**